# Windows Vista, Fails to boot in Safe Mode, or load past initial Login under standard conditions. HP Pavillion DV6000

Tags: windows-vista, login

I have an HP Pavilion DV6000 laptop, with Windows Vista loaded onto it.  Here is my problem (Besides still owning Vista):

When I try to boot the computer in "Standard" (no debug/Safe modes), the computer will load completely to the desktop, at which point it will simply "stall", the task bar is loaded, as are the icons, the clock, the start menu (which does not open), and the background picture.  However, that is as far as it will go.  After that, the "loading" cursor (the spinning circle merry-go-round of 'thinking') is a constant feature.
When I try to boot up into safe mode, the computer will load all drivers completely, however, after loading `crcdisk.sys` (The final driver my computer has), it will not activate `logonui.exe`/`Winlogon.exe`/whatever Vista calls the Welcome Screen loader.  I simply receive a black screen.

Here was what was happening previously:

The computer would BSOD past loading `netio.sys`, because one program must have botched and corrupted it.  After manually extracting `netio.sys`, `tcpip.sys`, etc, from a Windows Vista hotfix, I put them in place of the old files that were corrupted.

However, I forgot to add the `.mui` files.  Could this be my issue?

Also, while the machine was down, I deleted a lot of programs/services I had loading at startup, to see if I could get in to Windows (Previously, under safe mode, it would load to the login screen, but stall exactly 5 seconds after first displaying the login screen.)  I also deleted a few Bluetooth drivers the hard way, as they were also botching up the login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some root kits and other spyware will actually prevent the computer from being started in Safe Mode. The following tools should be able to remove it for you, but you'll probably have to install the hard disk in a clean machine as a secondary drive (so the spyware can't interfere) to run a full scan on it:

- [MalwareBytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org/)
- [SpyBot - Search & Destroy](http://security.kolla.de/)

Comment: If you'd like to know more about root kits, this web page will be of interest (you can read it during the scan operation):  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sony_BMG_copy_protection_rootkit_scandal

Comment: Thank you, very, very much.  While I feel a little dumb for forgetting that, you've probably saved me a lot of poking.  I'll see about getting the BartPE disks out.  Thank you very much.

Comment: I hope you find something and that its removal solves your problem.  Please post an update back here after the scan because if your problem isn't solved then we'd like to try to come up with some other possible solutions for you.

Comment: I would like to thank you for trying to help me, but all of this is a moot point now.  Thanks to sheer, dumb, bad luck, while running ClamWin from my Fedora Installation, The laptop fell off the stand, hit the floor, and shattered the power jack to mother board connection.  But you were right: Before it's untimely death, I found a few malware/virus issues.

Comment: I'm so sorry for you for having to go through all of that.  It's never fun when equipment falls and breaks.  I really do appreciate the update though -- thanks for taking the time to let us all know what happened.  Hopefully you can get your laptop fixed easily.